# Length of smallest DFA for the language consisting of string $x$ s.t. the number of $0$'s in $x$ is divisible by $k$ and number of $1$'s in $x$ is odd

Tags: formal-languages

"Let $k \ge 2$. Let $L$ be the set of strings in $\{0,1\}^*$ such that $x \in L$ if and only if the number of $0$'s in $x$ is divisible by $k$ and number of $1$'s in $x$ is odd. What is the minimum number of states in a deterministic finite automaton (DFA) that accepts $L$?"

This is a question from the (discontinued) GRE-CS exam (see question-50 in http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/walker/Quals/GRE_CompSci_1.pdf). The answer to the question is $2k$. And the answer is quite a plausible one after one does a bit of work and draws a few diagrams.

I have two questions:

(i) How to show rigorously that $2k$ is the correct answer?

(ii) Is there a general known strategy to deal with problems of this pattern (not necessarily this specific problem).

To give an actual specific example, consider the language $L_n \subseteq \{0,1\}^*$ such that:
$$L_n=\{s\in \{0,1\}^*\, |\,\, abs(N_0(s)-N_1(s)) \leq n \}$$
where $abs$ denotes the absolute value and $N_0(s),N_1(s)$ denote the number of $0$'s and $1$'s in $s$ respectively. It seems that the problem of smallest DFA (for $L_n$) can also be solved by first determining by inspection the smallest DFA for $L_n$ and then applying the minimisation algorithm for confirmation (as pointed by Rick Decker in comments).

**Edit**: It was mentioned in one of the answer below that the language $L_n$ just mentioned above isn't regular. The language I had actually in mind was this:

$L_n=\{s\in \{0,1\}^*\, |\,$ for every substring t of s, $abs(N_0(t)-N_1(t)) \leq n \}$

Comment: For (i) there is a well-known algorithm to minimize a DFA. Make a DFA for your language and use the minimization algorithm on it. For (ii) there is no general strategy for problems like this, but there are constructions for building the FA for the union of two FAs and the intersection (which you have here).

Comment: If there were less than $2k$ states then you would not be able to distinguish all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_k$ by Pigeonhole principle.

Comment: @RickDecker Alright, if I get correctly what you are saying about (i) ..... we can just apply the minimisation algorithm to the given DFA of length $2k$ (and as a result of applying the algorithm there will be no change in number of states). I am aware of the union and intersection constructions (though its been quite a few years since last time I looked at any of this) but I don't get your remark regarding (ii). Anyway, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @TobErnack What does $\mathbb{Z}_k$ stand for precisely? edit: OK I think I get what you mean by $\mathbb{Z}_k$

Comment: I mean the integers $\pmod k$.

Comment: If you could elaborate your comment (possibly as an answer if comment space is too small) in more detail it would be good.

Comment: @RickDecker You mentioned that there are well-known algorithms to minimise DFAs. As I understand, there are also known methods to compare equivalence of two (different) DFAs. So, in this sense, a trivial algorithm for minimisation (but probably highly inefficient compared to better methods) of a DFA directly follows anyway. One of my concerns, while posting this question, was whether any such algorithm (for minimisation of DFA) would be easily applicable to some arbitrary automaton $D_n$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (as in OP). Can you (reasonably) confirm this is the case for the question in OP?

Comment: I don't know anything about the specifics of minimisation algorithm (would probably be a good amount of effort just learning it) and hence the reason for asking.

Comment: The well-known algorithms for minimization take a DFA as input, not a parametrized family of DFAs. Hence they are not directly applicable to this problem.  For problems like these, you make a more or less educated guess of what the parametrized solution looks like, and then prove it's optimal.  The proof often relies, more or less explicitly, on finding a lower bound on the number of equivalence classes in the indistinguishability relation induced by the language.  Two words $u$ and $v$ are indistinguishable if, for every extension $w$, $uw \in L$ if and only if $vw \in L$.

Comment: In fact, an "educated guess" is often based on counting the equivalence classes of the indistinguishability relation.  The solution by Tob Enrack exemplifies this method.  Incidentally, if the number of equivalence classes is not finite, the language is not regular.  This claim is the essence of the Myhill-Nerode theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me slightly change your notation by considering the alphabet $A = \{a,b\}$
(this is just to avoid any possible confusion with the states, see below).
Let me also use the (standard) notation $|u|_c$ to denote the number of occurrences of a letter $c$ in the word $u$.

You are asking for the number of states of the minimal DFA of the language
$$
  L_k = \{ u \in A^* \mid |u|_a \equiv 0 \bmod k \space \text{and} \space |u|_b \equiv 1 \bmod 2\}.
$$ 
It is easy to design a DFA $\mathcal{A}_k = (Q, A, \cdot, q_-, F)$ recognising $L_k$ be taking $Q = \mathbb{Z}/{k\mathbb{Z}} \times \mathbb{Z}/{2\mathbb{Z}}$ as set of states , $q_ = (0, 0)$ as initial state, $F = \{(0, 1)\}$  and transitions of the form
$$
(p,q)\xrightarrow{a} (p+1,q) \qquad (p,q)\xrightarrow{b} (p, q+1)
$$
It remains to prove that $\mathcal{A}_k$ is minimal. Observe that each letter ($a$ and $b$) induce a permutation on $Q$, so that $\mathcal{A}_k$ is a *permutation automaton*. Furthermore, $\mathcal{A}_k$ is *accessible*, which means that every state can be reached from the initial state.

The result now follows from two results of independent interest.

**Proposition 1**. In a finite accessible permutation automaton, any two pairs of states can be connected by a path.

**Proof**. Let $\mathcal{A} = (Q, A, \cdot, q_-, \{q_f\})$ be an accessible permutation automaton and let $p, q \in Q$. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is accessible, there exists a path from $q_-$ to $p$ labelled by a word $u$ and another path from $q_-$ to $q$ labelled by a word $v$. Let $n = |Q|$.  Since $u$ induces a permutation on $Q$, the word $u^{n!-1}$ induces the inverse permutation (indeed, since the symmetric group on $|Q|$ has order $n!$, $u^{n!}$ induces the identity) and hence is the label of a path from $p$ to $q_-$. It follows that the word $u^{n!-1}v$ is the label of a path from $p$ to $q$.

**Proposition 2**. Every finite accessible permutation automaton with a single final state is minimal.

**Proof**. Let $\mathcal{A} = (Q, A, \cdot, q_-, \{q_f\})$ be an accessible permutation automaton with a single final state. Let $q_1$ and $q_2$ be two equivalent states: since there is only one final state, this means that, for every word $u$, the conditions $q_1 \cdot u = q_f$ and $q_2 \cdot u = q_f$ are equivalent. But, by Proposition 1, there exists at least one word $u$ such that 
$q_1 \cdot u = q_f$. Since $u$ induces a permutation on $Q$, one gets $q_1 = q_2$ and thus $\mathcal{A}$ is minimal.

**Second question**. You are asking for the number of states of the minimal DFA of the language
$$
  R_n = \{ u \in A^* \mid \left||u|_a - |u|_b \right| \leqslant n\}.
$$
Unfortunately, this is not a regular language. For instance,
$R_0 = \{ u \in A^* \mid |u|_a  = |u|_b\}$ is well-known to be a context-free nonregular language since $R_0 \cap a^*b^* = \{a^nb^n \mid n \geqslant 0\}$.

Comment: You are right of course regarding the second question (since, on the very least, I remember $R_0$ you mentioned being an example of a non-regular language) . I had a slightly different language in mind actually (but didn't write the correct description in a hurry). I will edit the description accordingly.

Comment: I have edited the second question to describe the language $L_n$ that I had in mind (in case you want to update the answer for that part). I haven't read the answer(s) in enough detail (yet) to know whether the second question would be significantly different (my feeling based on glancing the comments/answers is that it might not be).

Answer (score 3):

For any string $s \in \{0, 1\}^\ast$, let $(x_s, y_s)$ be the tuple such that $x_s$ is the number of $0$'s in $s$ and $y_s$ is the number of $1$'s in $s$.

Now $s \in L$ if and only if $x_s \equiv 0 \pmod k$ and $y_s \equiv 1 \pmod 2$, which means the same as saying that $(x_s, y_s) = (0, 1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_k \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Suppose $s = s_1s_2$ (concatenation) and we have already read $s_1$, which has $x_{s_1}$ number of $0$'s and $y_{s_1}$ number of $1$'s. Then in order for $s$ to be accepted, we need $s_2$ to have $x_{s_2} \equiv -x_{s_1} \pmod k$ and $y_{s_2} \equiv 1 - y_{s_1} \pmod 2$.

This means that after reading $s_1$, the DFA must be in a state in which it can only accept strings $s_2$ which correspond to tuples $(x_{s_2}, y_{s_2}) = (-x_{s_1}, 1 - y_{s_1})$ in $\mathbb{Z}_k \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

But as $(x_{s_1}, y_{s_1})$ ranges over all tuples in $\mathbb{Z}_k \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, so does $(-x_{s_1}, 1 - y_{s_1})$.

This means that for each pair $(x_{s_2}, y_{s_2}) \in \mathbb{Z}_k \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, the DFA must have a state that accepts a string containing $x_{s_2} \pmod k$ number of $0$'s and $y_{s_2} \pmod 2$ number of $1$'s. But these states must be distinct since they accept different sets of strings.

That means we cannot have less than $2k$ states in the DFA.

A DFA with exactly $2k$ states may be obtained as follows:

Initial state: $state_{0,\text{ }0}$

For $i = 0, ..., k-1$ and $j = 0, 1$:

$state_{i,\text{ }j}:$
$0 \rightarrow state_{i+1 \pmod{k},\text{ }j}$
$1 \rightarrow state_{i,\text{ }j+1 \pmod 2}$

The accepting state is $state_{0,\text{ }1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) (which generalizes the reasoning in Tob Ernack's answer) provides a general way to prove lower bounds for DFA sizes:

If you have a set $A$ of words such that any two words $x$ and $y$ in $A$ have a *distinguishing extension* -- that is a $z$ such that one but not both of $xz$ and $yz$ are in $\mathcal L$, then a deterministic automaton for $\mathcal L$ must have at least $|A|$ states.

In your case we can use $A=\{\mathtt 0^n\mathtt 1^m \mid n\in\{1,2,\ldots,k\}, m\in\{0,1\}\}$, which has cardinality $2k$.

---

(In fact, the size of the minimal DFA for a regular language is exactly the size of a *maximal* $A$ that satisfies this condition).

Comment: Myhill-Nerode is also usually a much simpler way to prove that a language is _not_ regular (by showing an infinite $A$) than the pumping lemma. I've concluded that the only real reason why the pumping lemma for regular languages is taught is that it's a conceptual stepping stone to the pumping lemma for _context-free_ languages, which does not have such an easier competitor.